# Server based password safe with local client

Tags: password-manager

These are my requirements:

- I want to host it myself, on Linux/Apache. PHP preferred, but could do Perl/Python or whatever else as well.
- Ideally free, or at least cheap
- Should have a good local client (KeePass-like comes to mind) that syncs/saves to the server

Is there anything like that?

Thank you!

Comment: Related question: [encryption - Self-hosted encrypted password managers - Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/15319/self-hosted-encrypted-password-managers)

Comment: Local client for which OS?

Answer (score 2):

One way to approach this is to use KeePass with a server that you automatically sync files to. Use KeePass as the client on each client system, and keep the data file on a filesystem that you automatically sync with a server.

Since you want to host it all yourself, the [OwnCloud](http://owncloud.org) server software with an OwnCloud [sync client](http://owncloud.org/sync-clients/) will allow you to do the sync automatically.

It's not exactly a server based client, but in some ways it's better - you always have the password file with you, so even if the server is down, you're still able to get to everything.